# SQLITE bulk UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to perform many SQL UPDATE Statements like these:

```
UPDATE cityd SET time_zone='-7.000000' WHERE locId = 173567;
UPDATE cityd SET time_zone='-8.000000' WHERE locId = 173568;
UPDATE cityd SET time_zone='-6.000000' WHERE locId = 173569;
UPDATE cityd SET time_zone='-5.000000' WHERE locId = 173570;
UPDATE cityd SET time_zone='-6.000000' WHERE locId = 173571;
```

I want to optimize the transaction time, so I need to use BEGIN TRANSACTION/COMMIT pair. How to write this in SQL Syntax in SQLtite Manager?

Edit:
When I use the standard syntax in SQLite Manager I receive this error message:
"SQLiteManager: BEGIN TRANSACTION; [ cannot start a transaction within a transaction "

Comment: So the code that's running your SQL statements is already putting a transaction around them. Thus you don't need to wrap a transaction around them in this case…

Answer (score 20):

According on [SQL Documention](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), there are two supported syntax of `CASE`

```
CASE x WHEN w1 THEN r1 WHEN w2 THEN r2 ELSE r3 END

CASE WHEN x = w1 THEN r1 WHEN x = w2 THEN r2 ELSE r3 END
```

So your multiple `UPDATE` statements can be further simplified into

```
UPDATE  cityd
SET     time_zone = CASE locId
                        WHEN 173567 THEN '-7.000000'
                        WHEN 173568 THEN '-8.000000'
                        WHEN 173569 THEN '-6.000000'
                        WHEN 173570 THEN '-5.000000'
                        WHEN 173571 THEN '-6.000000'
                    END
WHERE   locId IN (173567, 173568, 173569, 173570, 173571)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It really helped me. I m using sqlcipher and I'm creating a random flag saved in a column.

Comment: good! very good!

Comment: This is 10x slower for me when using transaction for everything. Perhaps this is only faster if you aren't using any transactions for anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
.....YOUR SQL Statements here

COMMIT;
```

Comment: when I type this in SQLite Manager I receive this error:
"SQLiteManager: BEGIN TRANSACTION; [ cannot start a transaction within a transaction "

Comment: It looks like SQLiteManager is by default running your SQls in a transaction, but i am not sure.